# Excel not returning the right value in using "IF" function

Tags: excel

I am trying to see any of 3 values are not "#VALUE!" by applying this statement:

These values are in columns B,C and D. it works in most rows but not all.

=IF(B1>0,1,(IF(C1>0,1,(IF(D1>0,1,0)))))

You can see Row 14 is not working

[image]

Comment: It only works if column B is a number greater than zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is nested so first it checks `IF B1>0` then if that is true it checks `IF C1>0` otherwise it ends. Instead use OR to check if any of those are true.

`=IF(OR(B1>0,C1>0,D1>0),"TRUE","FALSE")`

Alternatively if your number might be equal to 0 or negative use ISNUMBER. `=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(B1),ISNUMBER(C1),ISNUMBER(D1)),"TRUE","FALSE")`

Comment: great Basbadger. Can you fix so that it returns true if even one of the cells has value? The one you wrote only returns true if all have values

Comment: great, the second one is working correctly. The first one only works when all have numbers not  "#VALUE!"

Comment: @amir That's because with `B1>0` it evaluates if an error is greater than 0 which still an error. the second ones work because an error is not a number so it evaluates as false. You could use `IFERRROR` around each evaluation, but that gets messy. `ISNUMBER` is probably the better option here. Alternatively you could wrap your other equations in `IFERROR` so they would be blank or display a non number which should work correctly I believe.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see if any of the cells is a number, you can use count:

```
=COUNT(B1:D1)>0
```

If you want to see if any of them contain a number greater than 0, try:

```
=OR(IF(ISNUMBER(B1:D1),B1:D1>0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check that formula,

```
=IFERROR(D1,IFERROR(C1,IFERROR(B1,0)))
```